# Экспорт MySQL в CSV с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, csv, export

Как реализовать экспорт в CSV, но без записи в файл, а скачиванием?
Принцип такой: человек на сайте нажимает кнопку "Экспорт", потом берутся данные из таблицы (`SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status = 'В процессе'`), и файл export.csv скачивается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После исполнения SLQ запроса выводим заголовки скачивания файла и в цикле построчно выводим его содержимое.

```
<?php
    
    
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status = 'В процессе'");
        
    if ($result) {
       header('Content-Type: text/csv');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pedidos.csv"');
        
       while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo implode(',', $row);
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
```

Пример кода [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=f0cae057bc5785b67dce3776f8e57e60&sqlses=95bbf3409b095a85248973fa83c6260f)